# how to write logfile in tortoisehg

Tags: logging, tortoisehg

I use tortoisehg 2.3 with win7. So I need to get information like in hg log command in external txt file. Does tortoisehg have any logfile for console or can I get this one by another console command?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone has already logged [an issue](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/2264/allow-to-export-the-log-view-content-to) for TortoiseHg to do something similar. Consider voting for it.